# Autoload lines in leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I am trying to develop a map with openstreetmap and leaflet.js.
I have a database that contains more than 150,000 data. I can not display them all simultaneously.
So I developed a php script that will query the database and returns a GeoJSON code. It will be called by the JavaScript script.
I am using this project I found on github: https://github.com/chillly/plaques

Here are my current scripts (they work):

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `donnees` (
`data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `data_longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `data_portee` float NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

PHP code:

```
/*
 * ajxplaque.php
 * returns plaque points as geojson 
 */

// get the server credentials from a shared import file
$idb= "../include/db.php";
include $idb;

if (isset($_GET['bbox'])) {
    $bbox=$_GET['bbox'];
} else {
    // invalid request
    $ajxres=array();
    $ajxres['resp']=4;
    $ajxres['dberror']=0;
    $ajxres['msg']='missing bounding box';
    sendajax($ajxres);
}
// split the bbox into it's parts
list($left,$bottom,$right,$top)=explode(",",$bbox);

$sql="SELECT data_id,data_latitude,data_longitude,data_portee FROM porteerdi.donnees WHERE data_longitude>=".$left." AND data_longitude<=".$right." AND data_latitude>=".$bottom." AND data_latitude<=".$top;
$data = array(); //setting up an empty PHP array for the data to go into
if($result = db_query($bdd, $sql)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
$ajxres=array(); // place to store the geojson result
$features=array(); // array to build up the feature collection
$ajxres['type']='FeatureCollection';

for($i=0;$i<count($data)-1;$i++){
    $lat=$data[$i]['data_latitude'];
    $lon=$data[$i]['data_longitude'];
    $prop=array();
    $prop['plaqueid']=$data[$i]['data_id'];
    $prop['plaquedesc']=$data[$i]['data_portee'];
    $prop['colour']="blue";
    $prop['imageid']="op6298.jpg";
    $f=array();
    $geom=array();
    $coords=array();

    $geom['type']='Point';
    $coords[0]=floatval($lon);
    $coords[1]=floatval($lat);

    $geom['coordinates']=$coords;
    $f['type']='Feature';
    $f['geometry']=$geom;
    $f['properties']=$prop;

    $features[]=$f;

}

// add the features array to the end of the ajxres array
$ajxres['features']=$features;
// tidy up the DB
$db = null;
sendajax($ajxres); // no return from there

function sendajax($ajx) {
    // encode the ajx array as json and return it.
    $encoded = json_encode($ajx);
    exit($encoded);
}
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT code :

```
/*
 * global variables
 */
var map;            // global map object
var lyrOsm;         // the Mapnik base layer of the map
var lyrPlq;         // the geoJson layer to display plaques with
var blueicon;       // a blue icon for blue plaques 
var greenicon;      // a green icon for green plaques
var whiteicon;      // a white icon for white plaques

// when the whole document has loaded call the init function
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {       
    // map stuff
    // create the icons
    blueicon=L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'images/blueplaque.png',
        iconSize:     [24, 24], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [12, 23], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        popupAnchor:  [0, -12]  // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });
    greenicon=L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'images/greenplaque.png',
        iconSize:     [24, 24], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [12, 23], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        popupAnchor:  [0, -12]  // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor

    });
    whiteicon=L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'images/whiteplaque.png',
        iconSize:     [24, 24], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [12, 23], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        popupAnchor:  [0, -12]  // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor

    });

    // base layer
    var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';    
    var osmAttrib='Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

    lyrOsm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
        minZoom: 9, 
        maxZoom: 19, 
        attribution: osmAttrib
    });

    // a geojson layer
    lyrPlq = L.geoJson(null, {
        pointToLayer: setIcon
        }
    );

    // set the starting location for the centre of the map
    var start = new L.LatLng(53.7610,-0.3529);  

    // create the map
    map = new L.Map('mapdiv', {     // use the div called mapdiv
        center: start,              // centre the map as above
        zoom: 12,                   // start up zoom level
        layers: [lyrOsm,lyrPlq]     // layers to add 
    });

    // create a layer control
    // add the base layers
    var baseLayers = {
        "OpenStreetMap": lyrOsm
    };

    // add the overlays
    var overlays = {
        "Plaques": lyrPlq
    };

    // add the layers to a layer control
    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

    // create the hash url on the browser address line
    var hash = new L.Hash(map);

    map.on('moveend', whenMapMoves);

    askForPlaques();
}

function whenMapMoves(e) {
    askForPlaques();
}

function setIcon(feature,ll) {
    var plq; 
    plq=L.marker(ll, {icon: greenicon});
    plq.bindPopup(feature.properties.plaquedesc);
    return plq;
}

function askForPlaques() {
    var data='bbox=' + map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/ajxplaques.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: showPlaques
    });
}

function showPlaques(ajxresponse) {
    lyrPlq.clearLayers();
    lyrPlq.addData(ajxresponse);
}
```

I now want to display lines between points and do not show these points. I modified my PHP code successfully:

```
<?php 
include "../../../php/database.php";
$bdd = db_connect(); // Connexion à la base de donnée
// uncomment below to turn error reporting on
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_GET['bbox'])) {
    $bbox=$_GET['bbox'];
} else {
    // invalid request
    $ajxres=array();
    $ajxres['resp']=4;
    $ajxres['dberror']=0;
    $ajxres['msg']='missing bounding box';
    sendajax($ajxres);
}
// split the bbox into it's parts
list($left,$bottom,$right,$top)=explode(",",$bbox);

// open the database
$sql="SELECT data_id,data_latitude,data_longitude,data_portee FROM porteerdi.donnees WHERE data_longitude>=".$left." AND data_longitude<=".$right." AND data_latitude>=".$bottom." AND data_latitude<=".$top;
$data = array(); //setting up an empty PHP array for the data to go into
if($result = db_query($bdd, $sql)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}

$ajxres=array(); // place to store the geojson result
$features=array(); // array to build up the feature collection
$ajxres['type']='FeatureCollection';

for($i=0;$i<count($data)-1;$i++){
    $lat1=$data[$i]['data_latitude'];
    $lon1=$data[$i]['data_longitude'];
    $lat2=$data[$i+1]['data_latitude'];
    $lon2=$data[$i+1]['data_longitude'];
    $prop=array();
    $prop['plaqueid']=$data[$i]['data_id'];
    $prop['plaquedesc']=$data[$i]['data_portee'];
    $prop['colour']="blue";
    $prop['imageid']="op6298.jpg";
    $f=array();
    $geom=array();
    $coords=array();
    $geom['type']='Point';
    $coords[]=array(floatval($lon1),floatval($lat1));
    $coords[]=array(floatval($lon2),floatval($lat2));
    $geom['coordinates']=$coords;
    $f['type']='Feature';
    $f['geometry']=$geom;
    $f['properties']=$prop;
    $features[]=$f;
}

// add the features array to the end of the ajxres array
$ajxres['features']=$features;
// tidy up the DB
$db = null;
sendajax($ajxres); // no return from there

function sendajax($ajx) {
    // encode the ajx array as json and return it.
    $encoded = json_encode($ajx);
    exit($encoded);
}
?>
```

Now I have problems on the implementation of javascript code. I don't know how to replace points by lines.

Comment: That's pretty much code for a question. Can you describe your problem with a minimalistic example?